# Is it possible to use AWS Cloudfront to proxy Google Fonts?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, google-fonts

I have created an AWS Cloudfront distribution in an attempt to proxy requests to fonts.googleapis.com through Cloudfront. So for example, I'd like to use something list this:

https://xxxxxx.cloudfront.net/css2?family=Noto+Sans+HK:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap

To fetch the actual content from the origin at:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+HK:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap

I have configured Cloudfront with an origin of "fonts.googleapis.com" and set it so that it passes through all URL parameters, but still the origin responds with:

```
404. That’s an error.
The requested URL /css2 was not found on this server.
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Afaik, the way I've configured Cloudfront should act like a transparent pass-through.

I can't share all of the Cloudfront config settings here (there are too many), but perhaps someone can point me in the right direction?

Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in fact did work fine. I had just setup the CloudFront distribution incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the change OP referred to was to update the behavior to prevent the origin request from sending the host header.  Create a cache policy, remove the host header from the origin request and everything will work magically for you.